# How do I create a dynamic structure for my different properties in C #?

Tags: c#, .net, json, object, dynamic

The solution I found with JSON is as follows. 
I used Json.NET.

Creating:

```
public IActionResult AddProduct(ProductAddModel productAddModel)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productAddModel.ProductFeatures);
            dynamic json1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            dynamic output = new List<dynamic>();
            foreach (var item in json1)
            {
                dynamic row = new ExpandoObject();
                row.name = item.name;
                row.value = item.value;
                output.Add(row);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Reading the data:

```
var asd2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Aaa[]>(json);
            List<ProductFeature> productFeatures = new List<ProductFeature>();
            foreach (var item in asd2)
            {
                ProductFeature productFeature = new ProductFeature();
                productFeature.Name = item.Name;
                productFeature.Value = item.Value;
                productFeatures.Add(productFeature);
            }
```

Can I do it some other way? Without using JSON.

Comment: Might be worth explaining what the use case of this is - I guess the issue being that this can be done in numerous ways and I'm unsure of which to suggest unless we know what exactly you are trying to do and why you don't want to use JSON.NET?

Comment: I have products with different characteristics. I have values like name and price, but I need types that vary by product. Örnek olarak sayfamda araba satarken benzin yazmam gerek ama laptop satarken bunu yapamam. Yani ürüne göre dinamik özelliklere ihtiyacım var.

Comment: Use stored procedure with pivot